# Integral of a fourier transform in S(R)

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I know that $ \phi(w) \in \mathscr S(R) $ (Schwartz space) and then the test is asking to evaluate this integral:

$$ \int_0^\infty w \ \hat{\phi}(w) \ dw $$

I know that the answer is the follow
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \log|x|\phi''(x)dx -i\pi\phi'(0) $$

Looking at the answer I'm quite sure I have to integrate by parts but I don't know how to handle this because of the Fourier Transform. I thought I could swap the FT because $ \phi(w) \in \mathscr S(R) $ but if I understood correctly the integral had to be from $ -\infty $ to $ \infty $ and not from 0 to $ \infty $. Also the integrand is not even neither.

Can somebody please explain how to do this?

Edit:
$$ \hat{\phi}(w) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)e^{-iwx}dx $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $\xi$ convention for the Fourier transform (adapt it to your problem with the $\omega$ convention) $$\langle 2i \pi \xi \hat{\phi} ,  1_{\xi > 0} \rangle = \langle \phi', pv.(\frac{1}{-2 i\pi x}) + \frac{\delta}{2} \rangle = \frac{\phi'(0)}{2}+\langle \phi'', \frac{\log|x|}{2i\pi} \rangle$$ because $ pv.(\frac{1}{-2 i\pi x}) + \frac{\delta}{2}$ is the inverse FT of  $1_{\xi > 0}$, and $ pv.(\frac{1}{ x})$ is the distributional derivative of $\log|x|$

Comment: How and why did you add the $ 2i\pi $ ?

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio I don't know what [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions) for the FT $\hat{\phi}$ you are using, so I gave the solution in the $\xi$ convention, and let you adapt it

Comment: Added it in the post. thank you

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio I'm using $\hat{\phi}(\xi ) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)e^{-2i\pi \xi x}dx= \hat{\phi}_2(2 \pi \xi )$ where $\hat{\phi}_2$ is yours